# In the homebrew Gunslinger fighter subclass, what is the maximum grit you can have?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, homebrew, gunslinger

I'm reading over Matt Mercer's [Gunslinger Fighter Archetype](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/170778/Gunslinger-Martial-Archetype-for-Fighters), and after buying it I realized it doesn't have any maximum value for grit points.

Did Matt Mercer ever make a clarification on what it should be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Maximum Grit is equal to your wisdom modifier

I'm not certain if it is the same in the DM's guild version but the DND beyond version states:

> **Grit.** You gain a number of grit points equal to your Wisdom modifier (minimum of 1). You **regain** 1 expended grit point [...] You **regain** all expended grit points after a short or long rest. {emphasis mine}

No where does it mention a way to *gain* grit above this level, you can only *regain* grit that you have spent.

Answer (score 3):

## Your max number of grit points equals your Wisdom modifier

The [Gunslinger's Adept Marksman feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/gunslinger#AdeptMarksman) says about Grit:

> ***Grit.*** You gain **a number of grit points equal to your Wisdom modifier** (minimum of 1). You regain 1 expended grit point each time you roll a 20 on the d20 roll for an attack with a firearm, or deal a killing blow with a firearm to a creature of significant threat (DM’s discretion). You regain all expended grit points after a short or long rest.

It doesn't explicitly specify here that this is your maximum number of grit points, so some might find this wording ambiguous. However, given that that's the only thing that sets your number of grit points, and you regain any expended grit points on a short rest, it seems clear to me that the intent is for that number - your Wisdom modifier - to be the maximum number of grit points you can have at any point.

Otherwise, you could simply keep firing your gun without spending any grit to go above your Wisdom mod, and then the last line of the quoted description would mean you'd regain that grit when you expended it, too - functionally allowing your max number of grit points to potentially increase without limit.

---

In addition, [as linksassin's answer notes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/139783/33569), the description mentions "regaining" grit - which indicates that you can't have more than a number equal to your Wisdom mod. You can't "regain" something that you still have, so nothing allows you to have more grit points than your Wisdom mod at any one time.

Comment: Based on some Google results, it also looks like some older version(s) of Mercer's gunslinger subclass explicitly stated: "The number of Grit points the Gunslinger has can never exceed their Wisdom modifier." That said, I can't find any officially hosted versions of these older versions. (The archetype has been substantially modified since then, it seems.)